# Commons configuration library to add elements

Tags: java, xml-parsing, apache-commons

I am using the apache commons configuration library to read a configuration xml and it works nicely. However, I am not able to modify the value of the elements or add new ones.

To read the xml I use the following code:

```
XMLConfiguration config = new XMLConfiguration(dnsXmlPath);

boolean enabled = config.getBoolean("enabled", true));
int size = config.getInt("size");
```

To write I am trying to use:

```
config.setProperty("newProperty", "valueNewProperty");
config.save();
```

If I call config.getString("newProperty"), I obtain "valueNewProperty", but the xml has not been changed.
Obviously it is not the right way or I am missing something, because it does not work.
Could anybody tell me how to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're modifying xml structure in memory

> The parsed document will be stored keeping its structure. The class also tries to preserve as much information from the loaded XML document as possible, including comments and processing instructions. These will be contained in documents created by the save() methods, too.
>
> Like other file based configuration classes this class maintains the name and path to the loaded configuration file. These properties can be altered using several setter methods, **but they are not modified by save() and load() methods**. If XML documents contain relative paths to other documents (e.g. to a DTD), these references are resolved based on the path set for this configuration.

You need to use [XMLConfiguration.html#save(java.io.Writer)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/XMLConfiguration.html#save%28java.io.Writer%29) method

For example, after you've done all your modifications save it:

```
 config.save(new PrintWriter(new File(dnsXmlPath)));
```

**EDIT**

As mentioned in comment, calling `config.load()` before calling `setProperty()` method fixes the issue.

Comment: I tried that, but it did not work. What I was missing is that I needed to call config.load before the setProperty().

Comment: I am still getting some problems because it repeats some elements. Do you know where I can find a tutorial or coding example that uses writing? All the ones I found just explain how to read.

Comment: this might help http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration//userguide/howto_xml.html

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the following lines. I was missing the config.load().

```
XMLConfiguration config = new XMLConfiguration(dnsXmlPath);
config.load();
config.setProperty("newProperty", "valueNewProperty");
config.save();
```

It is true though that you can used the next line instead of config.save() and works the same.

```
config.save(new PrintWriter(new File(dnsXmlPath)));
```